# Could not find or load main class io.cucumber.core.cli.Main in spring boot Integration test

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I am fairly new to gradle and Cucumber.
I am getting an error while running my project don't tried almost every combination of dependency but still no luck.
although it builds successfully as shown below but still getting Exception as `Error: Could not find or load main class io.cucumber.core.cli.Main` .

1. Executing pre-compile tasks...
2. Loading Ant configuration...
3. Running Ant tasks...
4. Executing post-compile tasks...
5. Loading Ant configuration...
6. Running Ant tasks...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe by default Intellij creates a separate module per gradle sourceset, hence by default you will have a main module and a test module per project. Each module has its own classpath. It looks like you are trying to run test but with main module classpath, hence the class not found error.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get It but if I am trying to run separate feature file it is not giving e option to do that by clicking on feature file although I have gherkin and cucumber-java plugins